# Firefox / Opera Slow Page paint

Tags: performance, firefox, svg, opera, paint

I just finished designing this splash page for my startup: http://beta.mergenote.com/

Load time and initial render is a snap across all the browsers I've tested. (I haven't looked at any IE versions, but sourced it to friends who all felt it was similar enough to Chrome they didn't notice anything.. they aren't web devs though so if you spot something let me know).

The web page used jQuery for a simple slideshow, and for parallax scrolling it uses skrollr https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr

It uses an SVG sprite, whose width and height have been set to 3x the largest rendered size of any of it's icons (because of an Opera and Firefox rendering issue where SVGs don't get redrawn at their final size).

On Chrome / Safari, the site is smooth, fast, no issues.  On Firefox and Opera (and especially Firefox) the page takes a very long time to repaint on either resize or scroll events, and the animations are all extremely choppy.

I suspect it may be the SVG sprite, but I'm really not sure. The problems I'm having *may* intensified slightly when I sized it larger, but were there before hand.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it's pretty obvious that the SVGs are the issue. I've disabled them one by one and the page is now fast (it was lagging *a lot* before).

Even if a single SVG comes into the viewport, the page starts lagging immediately.

> It uses an SVG sprite, whose width and height have been set to 3x the largest rendered size of any of it's icons

Could you elaborate? This SVG is **2250 by 10350 pixels**. It will take *a huge* amount of RAM to rasterize. It could as well be 225x1035.

Comment: The reason the SVG is so large is because of a rendering issue in both Firefox and Opera which rasterize SVGs at their initial size, and don't re-rasterize once they are scaled.

Comment: Only a couple of the icons really need to be that big, so I'm working on redoing the layout of the sprite with that in mind, should end up 1500px x 300px if I've done my math correctly.

Comment: For images you don't need to rescale dynamically, you should really just use a PNG sprite with the exact sizes you need.

Comment: For various mobile versions + logo resizing these images are being rescaled, which is why I didn't use a PNG sprite. I wanted to try a single sprite for once instead of res detection based sprites. I'm not new to this game, just trying something new with SVG sprites and new to debugging SVG support (which has been a headache of an experience). :) Amazing job you did with skrollr, thanks!